# i want to show array of buttons in a single cell instead of creating bunch of cells in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

when select some buttons in the cell, it should add in array and it 
 should populate relevant data in next screen. 
[image]

Comment: You need to use tag list view a third party library.

Comment: `UICollectionView` is a good idea for that.

Comment: You don't "need" to use a 3rd-party library and for something this simple I think it would be a bad idea. Just give your cell a delegate property that the view controller (that contains the table view) sets itself as. And when the user taps a button, the action method of the button calls the delegate, which, in your case, calls the view controller that pushes to another view controller. The method that the button calls should carry a parameter that identifies which button was tapped so that the old view controller knows what to the populate the new view controller with.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your data into Array and then after iterating the loop for creating the button.

```
let arrOfString = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]

for i in 0..<arrOfString.count{
    let buttonString = UIButton()
    buttonString.setTitle(arrOfString[i], for: .normal)
    buttonString.tag = i
    buttonStringaddTarget(self, action: #selector(self.populateData(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.addSubview(buttonString)
    }
}
```

Now you can populate your data in an array using the following function:

```
func populateData(_ sender: UIButton?) {
    let index: Int? = sender?.tag
    // get the title/index of your button and add the relevant data in your array.  
}
```

Comment: If you `return button` your loop will only make one pass, and then you will return from the enclosing method.

Comment: Great! But still, your buttons will be placed one atop the other.

Comment: Please mention constraints or framing after adding a button to the cell.

Comment: adding constraints.. how can i do that through programatically ? could you refer any tuts. thanks!